# После отправки Ajax запроса перекидывает на страницу обработчика

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, form

Есть форма для комментариев, я беру введенные данные и отправляю их `ajax`-ом в `php` файл, там обрабатываю и записываю в бд. После этого, после обработки комментария, идет их вывод из бд на страницу. Я отправляю данные на страницу обработки но после этого меня на нее и перекидывает. Подскажите, как можно сделать так, чтобы комментарий появлялся сразу после сабмита, без обновления страницы и при этом, соответственно, заносился в бд?

Логика кода при ответе сервера такая, в зависимости от ответа сервера(0, 1 или 2) из массива выводиться сообщение из массиваa(ajax.js)

```js
$(function () {
$("#send").click(function(){
var author = $("#author").val();
var email  = $("#email").val();
var message = $("#message").val();    
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
url: "../php/send.php",
data: {"author": author, "email": email, "message": message},
cache: false,      
success: function(response){
    var messageResp = new Array('Ваше сообщение отправлено','Сообщение не оправлено Ошибка базы данных','Нельзя отправлять пустые сообщения');
    var resultStat = messageResp[Number(response)];
 if(response == 0){
     $("#author").val("");
     $("#comment").val("");
     $("#comments-lists").append("<li class='comment'><div class='activity_rounded'><img src='images/blog/cmnt-1.jpg' alt='image' /></div><div class='comment-body'><h4 class='text-left' id='author'>" + author + "&nbsp;&nbsp;<small class='date-posted'></small></h4><p id='comment'>" + text + "</p><a href='#leave_comment' class='pull-left reply'>Reply</a><div class='clearfix'></div></div></li>");
 }
 $("#leave-comment").text(resultStat).show().delay(1500).fadeOut(800);
   
}
    });
    return false;
    });
});
```

```html
<form method="POST" id="comment_form" action="send.php"">
  <input placeholder="Name" id="author" name="name"  type="text">
  <input placeholder="Email" name="email" id="email" type="email">

  <textarea placeholder="Message" name="message" id="message" ></textarea>

  <button type="submit" name="do_comment" id="send">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Вот обработка данных(send.php):

```
if($_POST['message'] != '' && $_POST['author'] != ''){

    $author = @iconv("UTF-8", "windows-1251", $_POST['author']);
    $author = addslashes($author);
    $author = htmlspecialchars($author);
    $author = stripslashes($author);

    $email   = $_POST['email']; 
    $message = @iconv("UTF-8", "windows-1251", $_POST['message']);
    $message = addslashes($message);
    $message = htmlspecialchars($message);
    $message = stripslashes($message);


    $date = date("d-m-Y â H:i:s");
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT INTO `test` (`author`, `email`, `text`, `articles_id`) VALUES ('$author', '$email' , '$message', '9') ");
    if($result == true){
        echo 0; //ok
    }else{
        echo 1; //error db
    }
}else{
    echo 2; //enter message
}
```

А вот вставка комментария  на страницу(insert.php)

```
$comments = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM `test` WHERE `articles_id` = " . (int) $art_q['id'] . " ORDER BY `id` DESC"); while( $comment = mysqli_fetch_assoc($comments) ) { ?>
<ol class="comments-lists">
    <li class="comment">
        <div class="activity_rounded">
            <img src="images/blog/cmnt-1.jpg" alt="image" />
        </div>
        <div class="comment-body">
        <h4 class="text-left">
            <?php echo $comment["author"] ;?> &nbsp;&nbsp;<small class="date-posted"><?php echo $comment['pubdate']; ?></small>
        </h4>
        <p>
             <?php echo $comment['text']; ?>
        </p>
        <a href="#leave_comment" class="pull-left reply">Reply</a>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
      </div>
      </li>
    </ol>
    <?php
  }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно чтобы файл обработки и записи в бд возвратил вам все комментарии, после записи последнего, и вы js выводите все комментарии.

Файл-обрабочик
    if( isset($_POST['name']) ){
    $errors = array();

```
if( $_POST['name'] == '' ) {
    $errors[] = 'Enter your name!';
}

if( $_POST['email'] == '' ) {
    $errors[] = 'Enter your email!';
}

if( $_POST['message'] == '' ) {
    $errors[] = 'Enter your message!';
}

if ( empty($errors) ) {
    // No errors, comment can be added
    mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT INTO `comments` (`author`, `email`, `text`, `articles_id`) VALUES ('".$_POST['name']."', '".$_POST['email']."' , '".$_POST['message']."', '30') ")
    }
}

echo $comments = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM `comments` WHERE `articles_id` = " . (int) $art_q['id'] . " ORDER BY `id` DESC");
```

**AJAX**

```
function call() {
  var msg = $('#comment_form').serialize();
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'blog-single.php',
    data: msg,
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data) //здесь будут ваши коментарии + той который вы только что записали

    },
    error: function(xhr, str) {
      console.log("Error: " + xhr.responseCode);
    }
  });
}
```

Или разделить ajax. То есть когда успешно записался в бд посылать еще один запрос ajax на select всех комментариев и выводить их с помощью js

Answer (score -1):

В ajax запросе в success последним запишите:

```
location.reload();
```